# Approaches to debug PHP library/vendor package code without editing library

Tags: php

I use a package that's installed using `composer`.  I'm getting an error in a method in one of the package classes. I'd like to see how the values get passed around and also check a few other values inside the methods that are part of call stack.

I could use `echo` or `var_dump` inside all those call stack methods, but I'm *not comfortable editing library source code*.

The library uses `whoops` so I get some goodness, but it's only shows the parameters passed but I'd like to see values of certain other variables.

Any other alternatives to this?

Comment: Doesn't xdebug work for you?

Comment: May I know what libray is this?

Comment: I'm using Raveren/Kint, it gives a nice presentation of var_dump, Available here https://github.com/raveren/kint

Comment: @MarkBaker Using xdebug, I would still not be able to check values in local / class level vars that are not params to methods.

Comment: @Mouli - whyever not?

Comment: @Fil I'm using Bolt CMS.

Comment: @MarkBaker - ah, right! I used xdebug trace with collect_params=4 and could see them. Just that I got a large one, which I'll figure out what to do with! Thanks.

Comment: For local scoped vars, you have `ini_set('xdebug.collect_vars', 'on');` and `ini_set('xdebug.show_local_vars', 'on');`; although long strings will only show the first characters of the string